# Open Colorbox when you click on the Select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I want to open a colorbox when the select box is clicked. It doesn't have to open when they select an option, I just want it to open when they click on the down arrow. I can't get it to work!

```
$("select").click(function () {
     $("#mydiv").colorbox({inline:true, width:"350"});

 });
<select> <option value="1"></option><option value="2"></option></select>
<div style="display:none;"><div id="mydiv"> content here </div></div>
```

Any ideas why this will not work??

Comment: Try putting code in document.ready, http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass it an element as well:

```
$("select").click(function () {
     $.colorbox({inline:true, href:"#mydiv", width:"350"});
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/KbhKf/)